# Clarification - DeGroot, Probability, Mixed Bivariate Distribution, what does this line mean?

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

[image]

I understand how the probability has been calculated in both orders here. But I dont understand the highlighted part. What does it mean that the sum is $0$? If it weren't $0$, would we then not be able to proceed to integrate the function over $y$ to obtain the final probability?